# Share class between activity and service in android

Tags: android, sqlite, service

I am working in a project where i have a service.Service is called from main activity. And service continuously inserting data to database,meantime Main activity is fetching data from database class.But i am not getting data from database in main activity.Why this happens? can't i use a class in main activity and service at the same time?

Comment: `But i am not getting data from database in main activity` likely because your code has some problems.

Comment: Without code it is hard to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Better handle through one instance (Singleton) of your database class else you will face a lot of issues when accessing your database concurrently from different classes.

Comment: Ok i will try.Thank you for your replay.